# jquery function is not working as event handler

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me why this function is not working ?

```
for(var i=1;i<=12;i++)
{
  var btn=$('<div>Button</div>').attr('id', 'id_'+i).button();
  btn.css('margin','10px').on('click', showId());
  btn.appendTo($('#buttons'));    
}

function showId(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass the function, not run it:

```
btn.css('margin','10px').on('click', showId);
```

---

BTW, you should also cache your `$('#buttons')`, and use event delegation:

```
var buttons = $('#buttons').on('click', '.ui-button', showId);

for (var i=1; i <= 12; i++)
{
  $('<div>Button</div>')
      .attr('id', 'id_'+i)
      .button()
      .css('margin', '10px')
      .appendTo( buttons );    
}

function showId()
{
   alert( this.id );
}
```

A few more things to consider:

- Moving the CSS to the stylesheet
- Appending all the buttons to the DOM at once

Comment: Indeed.  If you're finding this syntax confusing, you could also do `on('click', function(){showId()})`, which does the same thing.